# Modal dialog doesn't work with bootstrap 4

Tags: javascript, css, ruby, bootstrap-modal, haml

My code doesn't work with bootstrap 4. When I click on button overview, the page is darkening but a dialog doesn't show. It's work with old bootstrap. Can you help me?

```
        .form-group
          %label.control-label{ :for => "overview" }
            %a.btn.btn-info{ :href=> "#modaloverview", "data-toggle" => "modal"}
              INFO
          .modal.modal.hide.fade#modaloverview{ :tabindex => "-1", :role => "dialog", "aria-labelledby" => "modal-label", "aria-hidden" => "true"}
            .modal-header
              %button.close{ :type => "button", "data-dismiss" => "modal", "aria-hidden" => "true" }
                X
              %h3#modal-label
                titletextetxtetxtext
            .modal-body
              %p
                texttextetxtetxtettxtte
          .controls
            %textarea.form-control.input-xxlarge.allowMarkupShortcut#overview{ :rows => "10", :name => "overview" }
              - if @finding
                - if @finding.overview
                  #{meta_markup(@finding.overview)}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to change your code like this:

You need to add data-target property to you button and give the id of your model as value

```
form-group %label.control-label{ :for => "overview" } 
%a.btn.btn-info{ :href=> "#modaloverview", "data-toggle" => "modal", "data-target" => "#myModal" } INFO 
#myModal.modal.modal.hide.fade#modaloverview{ :tabindex => "-1", :role => "dialog", "aria-labelledby" => "modal-label", "aria-hidden" => "true"} .modal-header %button.close{ :type => "button", "data-dismiss" => "modal", "aria-hidden" => "true" } X 
  %h3
    #modal-label titletextetxtetxtext 
 .modal-body
   %p texttextetxtetxtettxtte .controls                 
    %textarea.form-control.input-xxlarge.allowMarkupShortcut

  #overview{ :rows => "10", :name => "overview" } - if @finding - if @finding.overview #{meta_markup(@findin
```